# Programmatic inclusion of conditional (browser-specific) stylesheets

Tags: php, css, drupal-6

How does one programmatically include browser-specific stylesheets with Drupal 6?

Long story short, I have a module which includes very specific style rules, which I want included only on pages which make use of the module.

`drupal_add_css()` works fine, but I may well need to include IE-specific rules for some bits, and I don't want to add these rules to the main site conditional stylesheets. The main site CSS is already quite lengthy, and these changes should remain segregated from the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to add the conditional stylesheet to every page, you need to use a preprocess function.

Preprocess functions are hooks that allow you to add/subtract content that will be rendered on the page. In your case, you want to use the appropriate `*_preprocess_page` function to hook into the point at which the entire page is rendered (and which therefore gives you access to page.tpl.php).

In this preprocess function, you should add a new variable like this:

```
<theme_name>_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (condition is met) {
    $vars['my_custom_stylesheet'] = "<markup for adding a conditional stylehseet>";
  }
}
```

Then in your page.tpl.php, add this new `my_custom_stylesheet` variable where you have the CSS stylesheet declarations in the `<head>` of your page.tpl.php, something like this:

```
<?php print $my_custom_stylesheet; ?>
```

That's it. You can use preprocess functions either in your theme or in a module, so use whichever makes the most sense and is easiest to write the `if (condition is met)` part of the code above.

Comment: This seems like the most complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional comments.

Here is an article about it:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Here is a snippet:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

See the documentation in the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you talking about?

You can do things like the following without including separate stylesheets:

```
color:#ffffff; /* default value */
_color:#ffff00; /* overwrite for IE6 */
#color:#ff0000; /* overwrite for IE7 */
```

Stylesheets should be be cached by the browser. By adding them in code you're braking this feature.

Comment: `*property` also works for IE7 and below. Are you sure that `#property` only effects IE7 or does it effect IE6 as well, like `*property` does?

Comment: I've never needed to use *property.

Comment: I don't think that answered my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this, Drupal 7 (I just discovered) does support programmatically including conditional css [as referred to in their documentation here:](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css)

Here's the call:

`drupal_add_css($directory . 'ie7.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'lte IE 7', '!IE' => FALSE), 'every_page' => TRUE));`

as it is included in the Zen theme for Drupal 7.

For what it's worth, this didn't help me at all in the project I was working on (it was Drupal 6...) and the question of whether or not it's even a good idea to programmatically inject conditional css, I think remains open.